# Why are all my SQL queries being duplicated 4 times for Django using "Prefetch_related" for nested MPTT children?

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework, django-mptt

I have a Child MPTT model that has a ForeignKey to itself:

```
class Child(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children"
    )
```

I have a recursive Serializer as I want to show all levels of children for any given Child:

```
class ChildrenSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="app:children-detail", lookup_field="pk"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ("url", "title", "children")

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super(ChildrenSerializer, self).get_fields()
        fields["children"] = ChildrenSerializer(many=True)
        return fields
```

I am trying to reduce the number of duplicate/similar queries made when accessing a Child's DetailView.

The view below works for a depth of 2 - however, the "depth" is not always known or static.

```
class ChildrenDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Child.objects.prefetch_related(
        "children",
        "children__children",
        # A depth of 3 will additionally require "children__children__children",
        # A depth of 4 will additionally require "children__children__children__children",
        # etc.
    )
    serializer_class = ChildrenSerializer
    lookup_field = "pk"
```

**Note: If I don't use `prefetch_related` and simply set the queryset as `Child.objects.all()`, every SQL query is duplicated four times... which I have no idea why.**

How do I leverage a Child's depth (i.e. the Child's MPTT `level` field) to optimize prefetching? Should I be overwriting the view's `get_object` and/or `retrieve`?

Does it even matter if I add a ridiculous number of depths to the prefetch? E.g. `children__children__children__children__children__children__children__children`? It doesn't seem to increase the number of queries for Children objects that don't require that level of depth.

**Edit:**

Hm, not sure why but when I try to serialize any Child's top parent (i.e. MPTT's `get_root`), it duplicates the SQL query four times???

```
class Child(MPTTModel):
    ...
    @property
    def top_parent(self):
        return self.get_root()
    

class ChildrenSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    top_parent = ParentSerializer()
    fields = ("url", "title", "children", "top_parent")
```

**Edit 2**

Adding an arbitrary SerializerMethodField confirms it's being queried four times... for some reason? e.g.

```
class ChildrenSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_foo(self, obj):
        print("bar")
        return obj.get_root().title
```

This will print "bar" four times. The SQL query is also repeated four times according to django-debug-toolbar:

`SELECT ••• FROM "app_child" WHERE ("app_child"."parent_id" IS NULL AND "app_child"."tree_id" = '7') LIMIT 21`

`4 similar queries.  Duplicated 4 times.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using DRF's browsable API? It initializes serializer 3 more times for HTML forms, in `rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer.get_context`.

If you do the same request with, say, Postman, "bar" should get printed only once.